# Getting a corresponding and non corresponding values from many to many table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a table structure like following:

Brands => Histories <= Users

Histories is many to many table and contains these values:

```
brandId, userId and points
```

I need to get all brands with points for which USER SCORED points, and ALL brands for which user doesn't have a corresponding value. It would look something like this:

```
brandId => 1 (has corresponding value) => 5 points
brandId => 2 (no corresponding value) => null (column points is null)
```

and so on...

Can someone help me out with this??

Edit:

Hi Gordon, I've modified your query to look like this:

```
select b.*, sum(h.points) as points
from brands b left join
     histories h
     on b.id = h.brandId 
     and h.userId = 2866 and h.brandId = 2
group by h.brandId
```

I need to have second condition h.brandID = 2 // or some other value so that it only returns 1 record at a time, if there is no record, I'd like the columns points to be null, if it isnt , it should sum all the points n show them in the column ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a `left join` and `group by`:

```
select b.brandId, sum(h.points)
from brands b left join
     histories h
     on b.brandid = h.brandid and h.userId = $userId
group by b.brandId;
```

If there are no rows in `histories` for the user, then the value will be `NULL`.

EDIT:

If you are using `left join`, then the `group by` should be on a column from the first table:

```
select b.*, sum(h.points) as points
from brands b left join
     histories h
     on b.id = h.brandId and
        h.userId = 2866 and h.brandId = 2
group by b.brandId;
```